# Misunderstanding of Styled-components concept

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to do a basic button with a text and an icon inside.
Here is my code right now:

IconNotification.js:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Icon = styled.svg`
  height: ${props => props.height || '24px'};
  width: ${props => props.height || '24px'};
  fill: red
`;

const IconNotification = (props) => {
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <Icon viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill={props.fill}>
      <path d="M12 22c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2h-4c0 1.1.89 2 2 2zm6-6v-5c0-3.07-1.64-5.64-4.5-6.32V4c0-.83-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5s-1.5.67-1.5 1.5v.68C7.63 5.36 6 7.92 6 11v5l-2 2v1h16v-1l-2-2z" />
    </Icon>
  )
}


export default IconNotification;
```

ButtonAddAlert.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import Button from 'components/Button'
import IconNotification from 'components/Icon/IconNotification'

const IconNotificationWithHover = styled(IconNotification)`
  ${Button}:hover & {
    fill: blue
  }
`

const ButtonAddAlert = ({ iconColor }) => (
  <Button>
    Add an alert
    <IconNotificationWithHover />
  </Button>
)

export default ButtonAddAlert
```

I would like that:

- When I hover the button, the svg icon changes color but only for this specific case
- Be able to also change the svg icon color by passing a prop (if I need to use the same icon in another component)

I feel like I am not understanding correctly the concept of styled-components because I don't see how it is possible right now.

If you know what I am doing wrong, please let me know!
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- `fill` can be handled by styled component.
- `IconNotification` should be referenced inside `Button` instead of the other way around because its styles are dependent on the `Button` state. This is a common pattern with CSS in JS.

**Icon.js**

```
const Icon = styled.svg`
  height: ${props => props.height || "24px"};
  width: ${props => props.height || "24px"};
  fill: ${props => props.fill || "red"};
`;
```

**Button.js**

```
import Icon from "./Icon";

const Button = styled.button`
  &:hover > ${Icon}${Icon} { // twice for specificity
    fill: blue;
  }
`;
```

Here's a link to the code sandbox so you can play around with it: https://codesandbox.io/s/n370mljrqp